# Which of the numbers in Google Analytics is the correct one?

Tags: google-analytics, web-statistics

I'm using Google Analytics event tracking to count the number of unique users.
A flag on localStorage is used to determine who is new and who is returning. I am aware that incognito or clear cookies makes the user looks like a new one, that's ok.

The problem is that on the GA reports screen there are **10 different numbers** for the same single event, that should all be the same!
Which one is correct? What do the others mean?

Normal Precision setting:

```
Total Events 12958 % of Total: 25.16% (51494)
Unique Events 12599 % of Total 26.36% (47790)
Event Category Total Events 58805 (100%) Unique Events 57241 (100%)
```

[image: Screen shot of GA events - normal precision]

Higher Precision:

```
Total Events 26045 % of Total: 31.64% (82313)
Unique Events 57241 % of Total 33.28% (76158)
Event Category Total Events 58805 (100%) Unique Events 57241 (100%) <-- same as before
```

[image: Screen shot of GA events - higher precision]

Thank You!

Comment: This is off topic as it not related to coding, and should probably be asked in the Webmasters forum.

Comment: Ok, how do I move it there?

Comment: You'll just have to repost it. I  don't think there's an easier way.